# Edge browser: css filter property

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

Are css filters implemented at all in the Edge browser?

```
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
     -moz-filter: blur(10px);
       -o-filter: blur(10px);
      -ms-filter: blur(10px);
          filter: blur(10px);
```

Nothing of these works.

Disclaimer: I'm testing it on version 20.10240 (it is on virtual machine, which I cannot update).

**Is there filter property for that specific version?**

**If not, is it fixed in the newer edge versions?**

Comment: Bookmark [the Status site](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/filters?filter=f3f0000bf&search=filter). It'll help answer questions like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is supported but you have to activate this in about:flags.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work fine with "Enable CSS filter property" enabled (which, BTW, was enabled by default for me). Sample here: http://codepen.io/ryanjsalva/pen/eZPpKJ

Answer (score 3):

Filters didn't work for me, because I had z-index: -1. Maybe that could help someone.

Comment: As far as I can remember, my problem was exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Opacity** was the problem for me. Setting opacity to 0.5 on the element with the filter effect was causing Edge to not apply the filter.

When I set opacity to 1, Edge started applying the filter effect again.

Also this question suggests that z-index might also cause the issue of Edge not applying a filter effect: [filter:grayscale not always working in Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939987/filtergrayscale-not-always-working-in-edge)

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, yes, it support filters, unsing the simplest form "filter: blur(10px);"

Try moving that up and putting it in the first line of the filters declarations, like:

```
          filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
     -moz-filter: blur(10px);
       -o-filter: blur(10px);
      -ms-filter: blur(10px);
```

See if it works. I know makes little sense, but microsoft is very straight forward saying it is normally supported

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. You can test it on this page:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/blurred-glass

The "Drag me" rectangles on right side should have blurred background, but they don't on IE and Edge. I'm testing on Edge version 25.10586.0.0.

Used code on that page is:

```
.bar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}
```